# logic error in finding the sum of a array

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

Need to find the largest and smallest sum from four of five elements of a vector(which is passed as an argument)

my code is able to pass 5/15 test cases. Can you please help with my code?

failed test cases:

> 254961783 604179258 462517083 967304281 860273491

> 793810624 895642170 685903712 623789054 468592370

> 140537896 243908675 670291834 923018467 520718469

[Link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/one-month-preparation-kit-mini-max-sum/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-month-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-month-week-one)

```cpp
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    long int sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5;
    long int min = INT_MAX ;
    long int max = INT_MIN;
    sum1 = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    sum2 = arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4];
    sum3 = arr[0] + arr[4] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    sum4 = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[4] + arr[3];
    sum5 = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[4];
    
    long int sum[5] = {sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (sum[i] > max)
            max = sum[i];
      
        if (sum[i] < min)
            min = sum[i];
    }

    cout << min << " " << max;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us, which testcases you use.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, How do you call this function? And what is the data in one of the failed test-cases? Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program? Also please include the actual assignment/exercise text in your question, what are the requirements? Why do you use such strange order for calculating the sums?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the code. Can you give one of the failing test cases?

Comment: If your vector is really of 5 elements, then you may want `std::array<int, 5> arr`.

Comment: Are you solving a leetcode (or other coding site) problem?
Hint find a use for std::sort.

Comment: What if your vector doesn't have 5 elements or is empty?

Comment: I don't understand the failure test case you shared. Is it the vector elements' values? If yes, then vector length is definitely not 5.

Comment: No links please. Sometimes they might require registration (which few of us want to do), or the link might become invalid or the site change, or the contents might change without warning. Copy-paste (as text) into your question as well.

Comment: You get the integer overflow. All first parameters of each sum should be like `sum1 = static_cast<long int>(arr[0]) + arr[1] + ... `. Assuming it's Linux, it should work.

Comment: @Sina This is yet another case of not knowing C++ properly enough to involve yourself in questions on LeetCode.  The leetcode site, and other "competitive coding" sites assume you know the language you will be using well enough to not make simple mistakes like this -- those sites ask random puzzle questions geared towards *experienced* programmers.  Knowing to use an integer type that will not overflow is basic C++ knowledge.  Using leetcode to learn C++ is a waste of time, as that site (and others) are not there to teach C++.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is hard to read , why not try **sort**.

```
#include<algorithm>
sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
long int min = arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3];
long int max = arr[1]+arr[2]+arr[3]+arr[4];
cout << min << " " << max;
```

Comment: The sum of 5 ints can overflow int.

Comment: This is definitely an obvious solution, but without details from the OP, we cannot know if this actually addresses their issue.

Comment: this code worked. But it produced the same result as mine. 5/15 test cases  passed. The link to op: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/one-month-preparation-kit-mini-max-sum/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-month-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-month-week-one

Comment: @Sina, change the vector<int> to vector<long> in the function argument and in the main function.

Comment: @WorryNice, please edit your answer.

Comment: @Sina change all vector<int> to vector<long int> and 15/15 test cases passed.

Comment: Nit-picking: On Windows / MSVC, `sizeof (int) == sizeof (long)`. With `long long`, you're on the safe side. [Demo on CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dvcGazeoj)